# Keytool auto generating subjectKeyIdentifier attribute while generating the csr

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, x509certificate, keytool, pki

I am generating keystore for mulesoft application using below article
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/tls-configuration#requirements

I am exporting the certificate to CSR format for CA Signing.
It automatically appends X509v3 Subject Key Identifier attribute which is an unauthorized extension in my organisation. can someone tell me how to suppress this attribute

[image]

Comment: Just wondering, why SKI extension is unauthorized in your organization?

Answer (score 0):

From `keytool` man page:

> The    subjectKeyIdentifier   extension   is   always   created.

However, not all is lost.

A CA only needs to accept the public key from a certification request.  Everything else within the request can be used or ignored by the CA as it chooses.  For example, it may ignore the Subject in the request and use the one added to its database when you registered.  Similarly, it can add (or not) any extension it deems fit.

Speak to your CA and ask them to remove the extension.